# Facebook Timeline Width won't change

Tags: html, css, facebook, plugins

I've used the facebook timeline plugin from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

I'm trying to widen it to fit this page, but can't seem to do so by editing the data-width

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/barexamplepage/" 
data-tabs="timeline" data-width="1000" 
data-height=1000" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" 
data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
<div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/barexamplepage/">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/barexamplepage/">Local Bar</a>
</blockquote></div></div>
<ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
```

How can I manage to do this?

My website where I'm using it is here: http://www.paddykeoghgoode.com/bar/blog.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that can be done. The timeline max width allowed is 500px. It even says that on the page.

However, if you wanted to re-size this (in a hackish way) you should resize this div:

`<div class="_2p3a" style="min-width: 180px; width: 500px;">`

There are several other divs/elements inside there that you will also have to resize. But that should get you on the right path.

Comment: Sure thing! Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Edit your post with what you tried instead of just saying it didn't work. I was able to resize **your** timeline using Firefox's inspector. So I know it works.